# Server Error TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I am getting this error.
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

[image]

my code is

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const AuthContext = createContext();

  const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
   user: null,
  token: "",
  });

// config axios
 if (process.server) {
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API;
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${auth?.token}`;
} else {
 axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API;
 axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${auth?.token}`;
 }

 useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.getItem("auth")) {
  setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth")));
}
  }, []);

  return (
 <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>
  {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

Comment: You forgot to add `< AuthProvider>` somewhere in your components tree

Comment: yes it works i forgot to add <AuthProvider> in _app.js file in NextJs project

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing (TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))) is usually thrown when you try to iterate over a variable that is undefined or null.

In your code, I suspect that the error may be related to the auth?.token expression in your Axios configuration code. The ?. operator is used to safely access properties of an object that may be null or undefined, but it requires that the object itself is defined. If auth is null or undefined, then attempting to access auth.token will throw an error.